# Trouble with Linq Select Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to query my Database for a single record ins three steps and I am having problems getting the result that I am looking for.  These are the steps that I created:

```
client = client
    .Where(s => s.CompanyName.Contains(name));

var res = client.Select(x => x.ID);

Tracker = Tracker
    .Where(s => s.ClientId.Equals(client.Select(x => x.ID)));
```

Debugging the code indicated that steps one and two worked correctly and generated the data that I needed to run my third query, which should provide the whole record, utilizing the result of the second step.

The third and last steps generated the following error:

> "The LINQ expression `DbSet<TimeTrackerViewModel>().Where(t => t.ClientId.Equals(DbSet<ClientsViewModel>().Where(c => c.CompanyName.Contains(__name_0)).Select(c => c.ID)))` could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

How do I query my database, utilizing the query result from the second step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `ID`s in `res` to filter `Tracker` then you can use [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0):

```
var res = client.Select(x => x.ID);
trackers = Tracker.Where(s => res.Any(r => r == s.ClientId));
```

The above query will return a collection.

> I am trying to query my Database for a single record

If you want to return a single record then you could to use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0), either in place of the `Where` clause (using the same predicate), or after the `Where` (you could consider [`Single()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=net-6.0) if you know there's exactly 1 matching record). But you should also consider what you expect to happen if multiple records match the `name` parameter in your first query and how you would handle that.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
var trakers = (from c in client.Where(s => s.CompanyName.Contains(name))
              join t in tracker
                  on c.ID
                  equals t.ClientId
              select t).ToList();
```

So you do only a query on db.

Answer (score -1):

After reading several related posts, I was able to combine thier ideas into a single working solution as posted below:

```
                var client = _context.ClientsViewModel
                    .Where(s => s.CompanyName.Contains(name))
                    .Select(x => x.ID).ToList();

                Tracker = Tracker
                    .Where(s => s.ClientId == client[0])
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: You could return a single ID in the 1st query rather than a list: `var clientId = _context.ClientsViewModel.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CompanyName.Contains(name)).ID`